# Using delegate methods with semaphores in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, delegates, semaphore

Hi I am using delegate methods in Objective C and need some help. I have the following functions A and B. B is the delegate function.

```
-(BOOL) A{
    int cmd = 73;
    [_serialPort sendData:cmd];
    NSLog("Hello");
    return TRUE;
}

//Delegate function

-(void) B{
    //When some data is received on the serial port function B is called
}
```

But function A doesn't wait until data is received on the serial port. How do I block function A  until some data is received on the serial port? I am using ORSSerialPort library in objective-C.

Comment: Blocking is a bad idea anyway.  You would normally just handle the incoming data asynchronously through your delegate method

Comment: @ZaidPathan Yes when I want to send data over a serial port, I call function A.

Comment: Where are you calling method `A`?

Comment: You should call method `A` from `B` when delegate get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like ORSSerialPort already uses a delegate for when you receive data.

```
- (void)serialPort:(ORSSerialPort *)serialPort didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // Assuming the delegate has method A
    [self A];
}
```

`-serialPort:didReceiveData:` is the delegate method from ORSSerialPort.

The code above will basically wait until data is received, and then once it happened, it will call A.